# rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The alternating harmonic series $a:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n}$ converges by the Leibnitz-criteria. Now consider the following rearrangement of this series given by:
\begin{align}
S:=1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-...+\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n-2}-\frac{1}{4n}+...
\end{align}
I want to see that this series converges aswell and has the same value $a$. I am stuck with this one. Does someone have a hint how to start this?

Edit: this not a duplicate to the question in the link below since I am asking on how to get the limit value of this series.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I don't think it is an duplicate because the question in your link is way more general

Comment: @TheSimpliFire my series is  a diffrent one tho....

Comment: It uses the same principle. Try it with your series.

Comment: This is a harmless rearrangement as the terms move by a constant displacement. Trouble occurs when terms get "rejected to infinity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $S_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of the alternating harmonic series, and let $T_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of the given rearrangement. Then $S_{4n}= T_{4n}$ for all $n.$  How far from $T_{4n}$ can $T_{4n+1},T_{4n+2},T_{4n+3}$ be?

Comment: Not very far since the sequence of summands of the rearranged series form a sequence that converges to zero! Thanks, I got it!